# Check if the number is contained within Dictionary array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have Dictionary that the key is an array of int, and the value is a string. How can I get the value by check if `int` is contained in the key array?

```
public static Dictionary<int[], string> MyDic = new Dictionary<int[], string>
{
    {new int[]{2,25},"firstValue"},
    {new int[]{3,91,315,322},"secondValue"}
};
```

I have :

```
int number=91;
string value=?;
```

I need the value will get `"secondValue"`

Comment: Can you have a case where the one key array contains the same number as a different key array? (but not all values the same)? For example can `91`  be part of the key both for the first and the second values?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a good use of a dictionary, to be honest. It feels like it would be better as a list of items, where each item contains a collection of integers and a name. Aside from anything else, that would allow you to express intent in the form of names.

Comment: Gilad Green - It can not happen

Comment: Using a reference type like `int[]` as a key to your Dictionary isn't going to work as you expect, unless you provide equivalence through overloading of .Equals and GetHashCode. Do a comparison of the HashCodes of `var x = new [] {1, 2, 3};` and `var y = new [] {1, 2, 3};` and you'll see the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use contains and a foreach loop (more readable than some other solutions):

```
string value;
int number = 91;

foreach(KeyValuePair<int[], string> entry in MyDic)
{
    if (entry.Key.Contains(number))
    {
        value = entry.Value;
    }
}
```

However, maybe a dictionary isn't the right choice for this.
Check out Gilads answer for another structure that you could use

Comment: While your solution works, it encourages the abuse of dictionary for a purpose it wasn't meant to be used.

Comment: Agreed. It's just there if OP for whatever reason is tied into the terrible structure that was created.

Comment: M-key. I would just have added some note about the problems with the original solution. - But I admit that is fully opinion-based.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a bad design choice. If the numbers don't repeat between keys (as you said in your comment for the question) then just flatten the keys into a simple `Dictionary<int,string>`. Just have the different integers all be keys for the same strings.

For example:

```
Dictionary<int,string>
{
    [2] = "firstValue",
    [25] = "firstValue",
};
```

In order to not repeat the same values but as different objects you can place a reference there:

```
string firstValue = "firstValue";
Dictionary<int,string>
{
    [2] = firstValue,
    [25] = firstValue,
};
```

In this case changing the value's content (not for a string as it is immutable but if it was some other object) for one key will change for all.

Answer (score 1):

```
string value = MyDic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Contains(number)).Value;
```

? is not needed, can not apply ? operand to KeyValuePair

Comment: in that case if your key is not here you will NullReferenceException

Comment: No It won't First when I put the ? operator it won't compile it self in VS, result in not null-able "KeyValuePair" FirstOrDefault will automatically return null

Comment: @Boo Does your statement mentioned in your answer compiled ?

Comment: @Boo You better give credit to me I tried editing the answer

Comment: @Boo Chirag is correct. [KeyValuePair is a struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx), so the null conditional operator doesn't work as per your answer, as it applies to reference types. The default value of a `KeyValuePair<int[], string>` is `(null, null)`, so it is possible to safely dereference the Value after FirstOrDefault. The return is null.

Comment: @ChiragMM that is why you can comment answer, like you could have done on my instead of creating a new one and then after i edited giving bad rep. what is it now? playground..

Comment: @Boo Yes As I mentioned in my comment above I tried editing your answer only but since it was only one character '?' change that too in code I believe any edit would require at least 6 characters to be modified your suggestion was valid except '?' operator :)

Answer (score -1):

something like

```
value = MyDic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Contains(number)).Value;
```

will return the first occurrence or null

Comment: @GiladGreen: There *is* no point in using a dictionary of this form, unless the OP actually has references to the arrays and will perform lookups with them. (Arrays don't override Equals/GetHashCode.)

Comment: @GiladGreen: But shouldn't that be a comment on the question rather than the answer then? It's not Boo's fault that the OP has chosen an unfortunate data structure.

Comment: well, I had assumed that his datastructure cannot be changed, like it comes from a external library,